# Top header is not showing with Bottom tab in react navigation v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to implement the bottom tab using react-navigation v5 but I am facing an issue. The top header is not showing in-app, When I implement header style is not showing. Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue? I really tried hard but was not able to achieve it.

Thanks

Note: I am using react-navigation v5.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  FontAwesome5,
  Ionicons,
  Feather,
  FontAwesome,
} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import MainAppNavigator from "../navigations/AppNavigator";


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={MainAppNavigator}
      options={{
   headerTitle: "Simply Dispatch",
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#495AEC",
    },
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <FontAwesome name="truck" size={size} color={color} />
        ),
      }}
    />
   
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: Add your `MainAppNavigator` also.

Comment: Header in bottom tabs is only available in React Navigation 6. You need to upgrade to the latest versions.